# C# - Convert DateTime format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: c#, ssis, datetime-format

I am trying to change the DateTime format from "dd/MM/yyyy" to "yyyy-MM-dd"

This is what I have at the moment:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("31/01/2000");
Console.WriteLine(date);

String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String dateStr = date.ToString(format);
Console.WriteLine(dateStr);

DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(parsedDate);
```

I get these results:

```
31/01/2000 12:00:00 AM
2000-01-31
31/01/2000 12:00:00 AM
```

Ultimately, I want the last result to be 2000-01-31

EDIT: Just to clarify my actual objective. I am using SSIS to convert a DT_DATE(dd/MM/yyyy) field into another DT_DATE(yyyy-MM-dd) field. So thought I would use a Script Component. 
This means I can't convert it back into a String.

EDIT++answer:

Sorry everyone, I think I've muddled up the question, but I can answer it myself now.

My goal was to convert source field DT_DATE(dd/MM/yyyy) into dest field DT_DATE(yyyy-MM-dd) in SSIS.

I first tried using a Derived Column by 'Replacing the original field' with (DT_DBDATE)field. This didn't work as it gave me the original source.

So I tried using a Script Component which led to the top part of my question, and lots of confusion. It simply didn't work.

The solution was to use a Derived Column by 'Adding a new column' and giving it (DT_DBDATE)field. DT_DBDATE's original format is in fact yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Oh hang on, just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373835/convert-string-to-specific-datetime-format <- this makes sense.

Comment: Where is the question here?  You've already got the code you want in the middle of your sample.  That date matches the date you said you want.  You could also try `dateTimeInstance.ToShortDateString()`.  You might also want to look into locales, and [the Culture class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).  This can help you automatically make your dates output in a specific format, based on system settings.

Comment: Sorry, I've since updated my question. Still pretty newbie at this. 

Would dateTimeInstance.ToShortDateString() give me the required format? 

What I want isn't for the date to be converted into a string with whatever format, but rather stick to the format I've given it as a DateTime obj. So maybe the Culture class will help, but I've been looking at that for a while now and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: You might not be able to do what you're trying to do.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx) - "When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format".  But you could still try.  I don't know what a "script component" is (I haven't done SQL server), but try simply `(DT_DATE)myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`.  If it works, it is because it converts the `DateTime` to a string, then to a `DB_DATE`

Comment: Hey thanks for the tipoff. After seeing that, I double checked what the format of (DT_DBDATE) is and lo and behold, it's in the format that I want. So all I had to do was use a Derived Column and "(DT_DBDATE)fieldname", which happily converts it.

Comment: "I think I've muddled up the question".  No problem.  The "best" thing to do at this point (if you want to invest the time) is to tidy up the question (preserving edits if you can) and title, and add your own answer.

Answer (score 19):

I think you just need to know about the ToString overloads:

```
string fromFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; 
string toFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15/01/2001", fromFormat, null);

Console.WriteLine(newDate.ToString(toFormat));
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found some other link as mentioned in my comment. 
I wasn't thinking. I need to actually store a DateTime object in that particular format without converting it back to a string, but I don't think that's possible.