# How to convert DateTime in dd/MM/yyyy to DateTime in dd-MM-yyyy?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have gone through many questions and answers here regarding Datetime format conversion. Almost all are related to converting the format to output as a String.

Now I want to convert a DateTime variable in local format **(dd/MM/yyy)** to a **DateTime variable in dd-MM-yyyy** format for providing it as an input parameter for an API method.

I have tried several method like mentioning InvariantCulture while parsing and all. Even tried using Hebrew calendar for setting current culture also. Everything is returning the DateTime in local format(dd/MM/yyyy) itself and when providing that datetime variable to API is returning error message as to provide datetime in dd-MM-yyyy format only.

Is there any way to convert a datetime variable to a specific format?

**Edit:**

Is there is any way to convert datetime to a specific format? I am attaching some screen-shots below for reference.

I am using a third-party API, and I don't want to disclose the methods.

[Method structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6M3f.png)

[Error response from the API method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9xk.png)

Now I hope there is now way for specifying a format for DateTime variable.

Comment: Can you please share the example where you send DateTime to API? What   DateTime is DateTime you cannot modify type. Probably you missing something else.

Comment: Share your code. So, it can be modified.

Comment: The `DateTime` structure doesn't have the notion of *format*. It is once you convert it to/from a string that the format makes sense.

Comment: Please show us some code of what you are passing to the API and what kind of API it is

Comment: 1. If your API method takes parameter of type `DateTime`, then you don't need to care about format just pass same variable to the method. 2.If inside your API method you somehow "print out" this variable, then use `variable.ToString(dd-MM-yyyy)` or `String.Format("My date: {0:dd-MM-yyyy}")` or `"MyDate {variable:dd-MM-yyyy}"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Convert DateTime format yyyy-MM-dd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756554/c-sharp-convert-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: I will edit the question and upload some screenshots if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - `DateTime` has no some formats. `string` that represents `DateTime` can have formats.

To convert `DateTime` to specific format to `string` you can use [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)
 method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string date = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

To parse `string` to `DateTime` you can use `ParseExact()` method:

```
string date = "02/03/2017";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

or

string date = "02-03-2017";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**FOR YOUR EDIT:**

`Convert.ToDateTime()` without `CultureInfo` tries to convert `string` to `DateTime` using your `PC` culture. If you want to use `Convert.ToDateTime()` use overloaded method that accept `string` and culture:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(someDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope there is no  way for specifying a datetime format.

Comment: @MONUTHOMAS There is no **a** datetime format, there are nearly unlimited format variants depending on your context. The user session has a culture information and that is used for the default formatting. If you need a specific format for a specific context define that format for that context and format the datetime. BTW The raw datetime value is stored in an Int64 (DateTime.Ticks)

Comment: @SirRufo Thanks for the info. I have also tried that to set the current thread culture to hebrew as the hebrew culture has the required format. But that also didn't work for me as that has returned the date in local format.

Comment: @MONUTHOMAS Do not try to solve a local problem with a global solution. Use a format string

Comment: @SirRufo but I have tried to convert using cultureifo invariant culture, it also return the error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'. As of my knowledge, the culture of the input datestring need to be provided in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use ToString Method and give pattren for parameter.

for example :
       DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")