# Convert string datetime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I got this kind of timestamp by parsing TCP packet '**Jan 27, 2017 16:58:15.688856000 India Standard Time**'. How to convert this string to Datetime in C#?

Comment: Use Split to get parts, and then analize them

Comment: splitting the string and parsing i can do.. is there any parseExact format (or) IFormatProvider for this kind of DateTime?

Comment: Well...No. For that string no. But you can use RegEx with enums to simplify

Answer (score 0):

use **cliver**

```
    DateTime dt=new DateTime
    if (!Cliver.DateTimeRoutines.TryParseDate('your text', Cliver.DateTimeRoutines.DateTimeFormat.UK_DATE, out dt))
    {
        //show message
    }
```

Comment: Timestamp Format is specific like UK_Date.. It can be any thing.. How can i convert to generic UTC format?

Comment: look at below answer or look at [link1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33298/C-Date-Time-Parser),[link2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/stringdate.html) you can simply try

```
string iString = "Jan 27, 2017 16:58:15.688856000 India Standard Time";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm tt",null);
```

or

```
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "MM-dd-yyyy",null);
```

After that if you want to format your own way you can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373835/convert-string-to-specific-datetime-format) like

```
2017/02/01 or May 07, 2016
```